# libpcap or PF_PACKET?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, libpcap

I understand this question has been discussed many times: Should I use libpcap or PF_PACKET (the data link socket) to capture packets?

Based on my research, libpcap is suggested over PF_PACKET almost everywhere, mainly due to its portability.

However, for my current project (which is used in a production system), portability is not a concern at all, all I care about is performance (speed, packet loss ratio). My program is running on CentOS 5.10 (kernel 2.6.18)
As far as I know, libpcap put a timestamp on each packet. Does this cause big performance loss? 
Are there other factors that make libpcap unsuitable in a high-speed network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I know, libpcap put a timestamp on each packet.

No, libpcap gets a timestamp for the packet from the OS packet capture mechanism that it uses - which, on Linux is...

...PF_PACKET sockets.

The Linux kernel time stamps incoming packets.  PF_PACKET sockets have multiple ways of reading from them:

- regular socket receives, for which you can either get a time stamp with an explicit ioctl (so you can avoid *fetching it to userland*, but you can't avoid the kernel time stamping the packet in the first place; libpcap, when using regular socket receives, always asks for the time stamp);
- memory-mapped access, which *always* supplies the time stamp.

Libpcap uses memory-mapped access whenever it's available; if you care about capture performance, you probably want to do so as well.  It's not easy to use, however.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Regarding "Libpcap uses memory-mapped access whenever it's available": Is this a feature after lipcap v1.0? What about versions older than 1.0?

Comment: Yes, that support was added in libpcap 1.0 (about 6 years ago); older versions of libpcap don't have it.  (Note that the version number in the name of, for example, Debian libpcap packages and packages for Debian derivatives such as Ubuntu has nothing to do with the libpcap release - "libpcap-0.8" in Debian may have libpcap 1.x.)